# Spring Boot micrometer gauges with variable tags

Tags: spring-boot, tags, gauge, micrometer

I'm migrating a Spring Boot 1.5.x application to use Micrometer (in order to prepare a future migration to Boot 2.x). We were using DropWizards metrics and many gauges, like to measure the number of jobs per type and category.

This number of jobs is variable at runtime, and also the categories and types. I do not find any elegant way to register gauges with a `MeterRegistry` when the number of objects to get a gauge from varies in time.

It'd be great to have a registration method where both the gauge value and the associated tags are returned by a function.

Thanks for any pointer,
Damien

Comment: This doesn't exist currently. Please open a github issue for this.

Comment: Are you measuring executions of jobs per type and category? Or in-flight jobs per type and category?